# MYSQL select records older than 1 day

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select records that are older than 1 day or 24 hours from a MYSQL DB. I can't figure it out why this statement doesn't work with `NOW()` and it only works if I explicitly add the date manually, here is the code for your review:

`date_posted` is setup as "datetime" in the DB table.

Works this way (Not desirable, for testing only)

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT my_id ) AS 'a'
FROM my_table
WHERE date_posted >= DATE_SUB( '2015-10-03 09:10:19', INTERVAL 24 HOUR )
```

It should work this way, but it brings a "0" count result:

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT my_id ) AS 'a'
FROM my_table
WHERE date_posted >= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR )
```

Comment: Did you try Curdate() ?

Comment: you're comparing dates and times, but want to deal only with dates. try `date(date_post) > curdate - interval 1 day`, so you ignore the time values.

Comment: Yes I did, I tried "current_date", "curdate()". Just tried, "SELECT count( DISTINCT my_id ) AS 'a' FROM my_table WHERE date(date_posted) > curdate() - interval 1 day" and it still returned a "0" count, it only works with the explicitly date as I mentioned above.

Comment: if you want records older than 24 hours/1 day shouldnt it be dateposted<= curdate()- 1 day?

Comment: I want to count if the newest  record in the database table is older than 1 day

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT my_id ) AS 'a'
FROM my_table
WHERE date_posted >= subdate(current_date, 1)
```

here `subdate(current_date, 1)` will return your the yesterday date
if your want to select only the yesterday post then use the following
`WHERE date_posted = subdate(current_date, 1)`

Comment: It only works  just like my code if the date is explicitly entered as this:
"SELECT count( DISTINCT my_id ) AS 'a'
FROM my_table
WHERE date_posted >= subdate('2015-10-03 09:10:19', 1)"
The issue is that, it sems that MYSQL isn't recognizing any of these calls; "current_date, now(), curdate()", very strange.

Comment: may be your data table has data only for the date `2015-10-02` not `2015-10-04` where `subdate(current_date, 1)` return `2015-10-04`.

Comment: I guess the SQL has to say "any records that is a day or older than a day".

Comment: First check this `SELECT max(date(date_posted)) FROM my_table` and see the max date of posting. What is the max date showing?

Comment: If I post something right now and run this SQL:

"SELECT count( DISTINCT my_id ) AS 'a'
FROM my_table
WHERE date_posted >= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) "

Shouldn't  it return "0"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91417/discussion-between-andre-and-payer-ahammed).